What is the right way to do Stim/sinter simulations using an HPC cluster?
I believe that if using sinter.collect to simulate an error correction circuit in Stim, setting the number of tasks is not sufficient to fully take advantage of a large cluster (since Python's multiprocessing module spawns processes inside of a single node). Usually I would use MPI for this task, but attempting to do that gets me the error
RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
which (from some googling) seems to be because of an incompatability between multiprocessing and MPI.
Does anyone know the correct way to use MPI (or other ways to take advantage of the resources available) with Stim/sinter?
(Alternatively, if one knows how to use a decoder inheriting from sinter.decoder without using sinter.collect, that would be helpful too)

Your use case sounds complicated enough that I recommend writing something custom. Sinter is only written to run on one computer, not a cluster. You could easily spend as much time fighting it to do what you want as bootstrapping something for yourself.
Something you could consider is finding the place in sinter where messages are sent between the central manager and the workers, and simply changing that one part to work on a cluster. It uses asynchronous message passing (as opposed to e.g. semaphores), so it could in principle be run over a network.
For writing something totally custom, I'll note that the actual sampling loop is easy to do. You get a task (shots+circuit+decoder+dem) in some format, compile a detector sampler from the circuit, compile a configured decoder from the decoder+dem, and then begin taking and decoding shots in batches of 1024 until the requested number of shots has been taken.
The annoying thing to implement is "stop when enough errors have been seen", because this involves coordinating the workers. This drives all the complexity (e.g. at the beginning you have no idea what the error rate is for a circuit, so you need to adaptively allocate shots and errors to the workers). Tasks often have wildly different completion times, and a very subdividable, so you likely also want some sort of work stealing functionality to reallocate already-allocated work.
If you can find an HPC library that does monte-carlo-until-X-events-seen, use that. I only wrote sinter because I couldn't find one.

Thanks for the tips Craig! I appreciate the advice.
